# Why does my footer also has links from another container?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have Facebook and Instagram links in 1 container, and another footer container for my footer.

I've checked all divs are closed, why does the links(href) also work on my footer? I'm new at coding so do correct me if any of the codes here are wrong!

This are the html codes (using bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-2">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="svg/facebook.svg" style="max-width:37px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-2">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="svg/instagram.svg" style="max-width:37px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
</div>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container col-12">
    <span class="footer">&copy; 2019 xxx Pte Ltd All Rights Reserved.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

My footer should not have the links(href)!

Comment: Are you sure about that code? Why don't you simply add some closing `</a>`?

Comment: It would be useful to have more context about the question like where you are running the code, what components and softwares you use

Comment: @NicoHaase omg what a mistake..... thank you!!

Comment: Little tip for future with things like this - [validate your code](https://validator.w3.org/) and you will see why you are having trouble - in this case because you do not close your anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the closing `</a>` tag:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-2">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="svg/facebook.svg" style="max-width:37px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-2">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="svg/instagram.svg" style="max-width:37px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container col-12">
    <span class="footer">&copy; 2019 xxx Pte Ltd All Rights Reserved.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```